# Eclipse can't find/open text files from path

Tags: java, eclipse, directory

I'm currently making an app which reads from text files and then does cool stuff with the words inside it. Now I unfortunately have the problem that Eclipse can't seem to find/open the text files. Since this is my first app I am not 100% sure if I did the whole "putting-files-in-eclipse"-thing correctly.

Here are two screenshots that pretty much sum up the whole problem:

[Error message when the method is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTDmr.png)

[My directories look like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQdTb.png)

I already wrote another program where I used similar pathing and everything worked fine.

Here's the code: (elemArray contains "wi", "wa", "f", "l", "d")

```
String[] elemArray = elems.toArray(new String[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){

        for(int l = 3; l < 6; ++l){
            checkFile = new Scanner(new File("texts/" + elemArray[i] + "monster" + l + ".txt")).useDelimiter(",\\s*");
.
.
.   does some other irrelevant stuff here
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need "/" before "texts", but it's hard to tell since there isn't any code here.

Comment: added code, doesnt work with /texts/..

Answer (score 0):

From the available information I suspect a working directory mismatch.

### Working Directory

Your working directory when launching your Java program is not what you expect. The `new File("texts/" [...]` will create a relative path.

You can specify the working directory in the [Launch Configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-java-local-configuration.htm?cp=1_3_6_3) in the *Arguments* tab near the bottom in the *Working directory:* section:

[image: working directory]

### Test/Debug

Extract the `new File("texts/" [...]` to a variable (it is quite a long line as it is). You can add an expression of [`f.getAbsoluteFile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getAbsoluteFile()) to ensure it resolves as expected.

i.e. rewrite like this (I would probably extract the string passed to `new File()` too BTW):

String[] elemArray = elems.toArray(new String[0]);

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){

    for(int l = 3; l < 6; ++l){
        File f = new File("texts/" + elemArray[i] + "monster" + l + ".txt");
        checkFile = new Scanner(f).useDelimiter(",\\s*");
```